# Speed : typedef vs #define in c++

Tags: c++, g++, clang

Recently I came across `typedef`s and `#define`s. Even though they have similar usage, one of them is a compiler token and the other is a preprocessor token.

This made me wonder about their speeds of operation, as one wants to be as fast as possible in competitive programming.

So, which one is relatively faster? An explanation accompanied with the answer would be great. Would the compiler used make any difference like `g++` vs `MSVC compiler` vs `clang` compiler?

Use case examples:
`typedef long long int;` and `#define ll long long int`.

Comment: No difference at all. Neither types, nor the preprocessor exist when your code is run.

Comment: No real different … but `#define` tends to be frowned upon in c++ …

Comment: Speed in what sense? Compilation time? They might differ in compilation time but most surely insignificantly. No other differences. Macros (`#define`) tend to corrupt code and thus are unwelcome.

Comment: You're caught up in premature optimization. In properly designed problems, a slow algorithm won't run in time no matter how much you optimize the constant factors and a fast algorithm will easily run in time without you having to optimize every single bit. Stuff like this rarely matters in competitive programming.

Comment: Please don't abuse `typedef` to make your code unreadable. Shortening variable and type names to a bare minimum _won't_ make your code run faster it will just make it harder to read and understand. Such abreviations are not received well here, in case you need to ask about your "competetive" code.

Comment: Using `long long int` for all your variables will have more of an impact than how you choose the shorten the name to `ll`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in performance, but preprocessor macros are not recommended because they pollute the global scope since unlike `typedef` they can't be placed in a namespace.

But arguably, `ll` isn't very expressive; it may make the code less readable. Consider using `int64_t` from [`<cstdint>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). It's nice because it's more expressive (`_t` clearly indicates it's a type and its size is exactly 64 bits, and so is future-proof, even when `long long` is 128 bits), and is relatively concise so no need to `typedef` anything.

Answer (score 4):

They both take the same amount of time. You won't notice any difference at all.

Also note that if used properly they are identical at runtime. Only in compile times they might differ slightly but that's barely anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about using c++ features, the better option would be to use the `using` keyword which is available since c++11 and specifically designed for this purpose. It is also compatible with templates.

Please note that, both `using` and `typedef` are semantically same.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Answer (score 0):

No difference in execution time, so you should be fine using either for competitive programming.

I personally avoid `#define` and use `typedef` for types as it is more cleaner and readable.